# Inconsistent indentation: 1 tab used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces

Tags: haml

```
= simple_form_for @pin,html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  - if @pin.errors.any?
    #errors
        %h2
      = pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error")
      prevented this Pi from saving
      %ul
        - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .form-group
    = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
  .form-group
    = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
  = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Inconsistent indentation: 1 tab used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces.

Comment: how do i remove it

Comment: Remove what? I'm afraid your question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this question is unclear. What behaviour do you want - no tabs or everything 2 spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of tab characters and spaces in your file. You need to stick to one or the other for haml to work. Depending on your editor you could probably fix it by setting the intendation character (most people use 2 or 4 spaces these days) and the reindent the file.